# First-order logic with conditionals

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

I am taking a course on Maths for Business and Computing and am kind of stuck with translating English sentences into predicates. I have researched a lot, but not really come across a similar example:

If the volume of the room is greater than 2000m^3 and the temperature of the room is greater than 20°C and less than or equal to 25°C then at least one window in the room should be opened (provided the room has windows).

My answer: 
$P(v, r)$ = The volume $v$ of the room $c$ is greater than $2000m^3$
$Q(t)$ = The temperature t is greater than $20°C$ and less than or equal to $25°C$
$R(w)$ = window $w$ is open

$$\forall v \forall c \forall t ~((P(v,r) \wedge Q(t) \rightarrow \exists w : R(w))$$

If every volume v of every room r is greater than $2000m^3$ and every temperature $t$ is greater than $20°C$ and less than or equal to $25°C$, there is at least one window $w$ open.

If anybody could give me some tips or recommend a resource that I could use for my studies that would be great!

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: The basic logical structure is fine!  Two small things: You need to change the $r$ in $P(v,r)$ into a $c$, and you need a closing parenthesis after $Q(t)$. Two slightly bigger things: you probably want to use a predicate $R(w,c)$ for 'window $w$ in room $c$ is open', and likewise have a predicate $Q(t,c)$ to refer to the temperature $ t$ in room $c$. And finally, I don't know if you can use the predicates as defined, or if you need to work with the numbers, so that's something you could look at, but again, the basic structure is correct!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! One quick question: What do you mean by work with numbers? Do you mean pass in values for volume and temperature or numbers such as 2000m3 and 20/25 Degree

Comment: Yeah ... Though then there is an issue of units as well of course. But you could for example define a function $temp(x)$ that returns the temperature in room $x$ in Celcius, and then you could use the expression $20<temp(x) \land temp(x) \leq 25$. Of course, that also assumes you have constant symbols for 20 and 25, and predicate symbols $<$ and $\leq$ as well.

Comment: And that reminds me ... If you stick to predicate symbols rather than using functions, I would use some more transparent symbols, like $O$ Or $Open$ for 'open', and even something like $VolumeGreaterThan2000m^3$.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first and foremost: you have the basic logical structure $\forall ( bla bla  \rightarrow \exists : bla bla)$ correct!

A couple of small things though:

You need to change the $r$ in $P(v,r)$ into a $c$, and you need a closing parenthesis after $Q(t)$.

You want to use a predicate $R(w,c)$ for 'window $w$ in room $c$ is open', and likewise have a predicate $Q(t,c)$ to say 'the temperature $t$ in room $c$. ... in both cases we don't know that we are talking about that specific room otherwise.

I would use some more transparent symbols for your predicates instead of $P$, $Q$, and $R$. Maybe $O$ or $Open$, and $G$ for 'greater than 2000 m^3', etc.

Then, you could try to use function symbols, so you can include those specific numbers as well. For example, if you have a $temp(x)$ predicate that returns the temperature in room $x$ in Celcius, and then you could use the expression $20<temp(x) \land temp(x)≤25$. Of course, this does mean you need to be allowed to use mathematical symbols in your logic expression, but you no longer need to treat the temperature as an object (and hence no longer need to quantify over it), which might be good.  And by the way, if they give you $<$, but not $\leq$, you can express the smaller or equal to 25 as: $temp(x) < 25 \lor temp(x) = 25$

Likewise, you could use a function $vol(x)$ that returns the volume of $x$ in $m^3$, so you could write $vol(x) > 2000$ or (if again they only give you $<$ but not $>$) you could write $2000 < vol(x)$

Finally, you could use a predicate $In(x,y)$ that says '$x$ is in $y$' to be used for the window being 'in' the room, and use explicit predicates $R(x)$ for 'x is a room' and $W(x)$ for 'x is a window'.

So with all those symbols, you would get:

$\forall x ((R(x) \land 2000 < vol(x) \land 20 < temp(x) \land temp(x) \leq 25) \rightarrow \exists y (W(y) \land I(y,x) \land O(y)))$

Comment: Wow, brilliant. That makes much more sense. So for another example:
 “If the temperature of the room exceeds 25 Degree Celcius the all persons in the room should be evacuated.” I could write:                 

     ∀x((R(x) ∧ temp(x) > 25) → ∃y(Pers (p) ∧ In(p,x) ∧ Evac(p))                                     
Where:
persons(p) =  p is a persons\n\n
evac(p) = evacuted

Comment: Not quite: *all* persons need to be evacuated, so the second part will be $\forall y ((Pers(y) \land In(p,x)) \rightarrow Evac(p))$